# Access to pandas dataframe object between requests via session key

Tags: django, pandas, memcached, django-rest-framework, web-architecture

I have a pandas dataframe with a loose wrapper class around it that provides metadata for my django/DRF application. The application is basically a user friendly (non programmer) way to do some data analysis and validation. Between requests I want to be able to save the state of the dataframe so I can have a series of interactions with the data but it does not need to be saved in a database ( It only needs to survive as long as the browser session ). From this it was logical to check out django's session framework, but from what I've heard session data should be lightweight and the dataframe object does not json serialize.

Because I dont have a ton of users, and I want the app to feel like a desktop site, I was thinking of using the django cache as a way to keep the dataframe object in memory. So putting the data in the cache would go something like this

```
>>> from django.core.cache import caches
>>> cache1 = caches['default']
>>> cache1.set(request.session._get_session_key, dataframe_object)
```

and then the same except using get in the following requests to access.
Is this a good way to do handle this workflow or is there another system I should use to keep rather large data(5mb to 100mb) in memory?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your application on a modern server then 100mb is not a huge amount of memory.  However if you have more than a couple dozen simultaneous users, each requiring 100mb of cache then this could add up to more memory than your server can handle.  Your cache and server should be configured appropriately and you may want to limit the total number of cached dataframes in your python code.

Since it does appear that Django needs to serialize session data your choice is to either use sessions with PickleSerializer or to use the cache.  According to documentation, PickleSerializer is not recommended for security reasons so your choice to use the cache is a good one.

The default cache backend in Django does not share entries across processes so you would get better memory and time efficiency by installing memcached and enabling the memcached.MemcachedCache backend.